# list index out of range loop Python

Tags: python, loops

I am running a loop (more as a iteration process) with the purpose of calculating the cosine similarity of a pair of texts files a a data set with 84 texts files. The logic I follow is to calculate it first from the document 0 and 1, then document 1 and 2 until document n-1 and n. The way I coded it is the following:

```
my_funcs = {}
for i in range(len(data)):
    def foo(x, y):
        x = data[i]['body']
        y = data[i+1]['body']
        tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([x, y])
        return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]


    foo.func_name = "cosine_sim%d" % i
    my_funcs["cosine_sim%d" % i] = foo

globals().update(my_funcs) # Export to namespace
```

Not surprisingly my code gives me the following error: `list index out of range`. Is there any way to tell the loop to stop when `i = len(data)` ?

Comment: You did tell the loop to stop, but the `data[i + 1]` is what is faulting. Perhaps you want `range(len(data) - 1)`.

Comment: Don't use `globals()` without great reason. Assume you don't have great reason unless you can explain why your reason is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_funcs = {}
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    def foo(x, y):
        x = data[i]['body']
        y = data[i+1]['body']
        tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([x, y])
        return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]


    foo.func_name = "cosine_sim%d" % i
    my_funcs["cosine_sim%d" % i] = foo

globals().update(my_funcs) # Export to namespace
```

I just made the loop to `len(data)-1`. Do you realize what changes it makes?

By the way, I don't agree with filling the `globals()` with so many functions. There are 84 of them. Unless you aren't using them for Python Shell use (for fast working), I would not suggest you to try this.